# OpenMP- no output

Tags: c, openmp, pbs

I have a C code that requires parallising with openMP. the code itself runs fine serially but not when parallised. the code is being run with PBS and i have included the batch script.

The code has two paralised regions, both within a time loop, which become serial at the end to print output files. ideally to have one output per time-step.

Serially i outputs a file every timestep, but in parallel it outputs the first file and continues to run indefinitely outputting nothing (including error files, both self made and system errors).

## The code

```
.#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private (dudx2, dudy2, dudz2, du, /*I_gap, I_gap2,*/ Ii, x, y, z) shared (V, Vnew, /*v_fibro,*/ hh) schedule(static)
     for (z=1;z<Z;z++) {
            for (y=1;y<Y;y++)
                for (x=1;x<X;x++)
                     if (hh[x][y][z] > 0) {


            dudx2 = (V[x - 1][y][z] + V[x + 1][y][z] - 2 * V[x][y][z]) ;
            dudy2 = (V[x][y - 1][z] + V[x][y + 1][z] - 2 * V[x][y][z]) ;
            dudz2 = (V[x][y][z - 1] + V[x][y][z + 1] - 2 * V[x][y][z]);

            du = (D/(dx*dx))*((dudx2)  + (dudy2)  + (dudz2))  ;


            Ii = MYO(x,y,z); //calls function with multiple multi-dimen' arrays

                       Vnew[x][y][z] = V[x][y][z] + dt * (du - Ii );
       }
     }





.#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared (V, Vnew, hh) private (x, y, z) schedule(static)
            for (z=0;z<=Z;z++) {
                    for (y=0;y<=Y;y++)
                            for (x=0;x<=X;x++){
                                                            if (hh[x][y][z] > 0) 
                               V[x][y][z]=Vnew[x][y][z];

                            }

            }

                        sprintf(str2,"V%d.vtk",tab);
            fprintf(outp,"%s\n",str2);
            userfile=fopen(str2,"wt");
            if(userfile==NULL) fprintf(outp,"Could not open%s\n.",str2);

                    tab++;

                    fprintf(userfile,"vtk header\n");




                for (z=0;z<Z;z++){
                    for (y=0;y<Y;y++){
                        for (x=0;x<X;x++){      
                        fprintf(userfile,"%g ",Vnew[x][y][z]);                      
                            }
```

## Notes

-the multi-dimensional arrays are 200x200x200 and there are 20+ of them which cannot realisitcally be reduced (represent biological cellular properties in a 3d tissue)

this lead us to investigate the possibility of a memory error. so we changed the batch        script to allow for 8gb per processor

-the code includes  and omp_set_num_threads (64) and the compile line is;

```
gcc -lm -lgomp -fopenmp -03 filename.c -o test ("-mcmodel=medium" has been trialed)
```

-the batch script is

mppwidth and aprun don't run

```
.#!/bin/bash
.#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=64
.#PBS -l mem=512G
.#PBS -M email adress@gmail.com
.#PBS -l walltime=20:00:00
.#PBS -N test
.#PBS -o ./
.#PBS -e ./

.#Modules!
. /etc/profile.d/modules.sh

module purge 

.#(Intel compilers)
.# source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
module load intel/composerxe/13.0.0

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=64

./test
```

Thanks in advance, and apologies about the abysmal spelling grammar and formatting etc.

Comment: BTW you use printf which is buffered, so you will get a "spaggetti" in out file. Substitute printf by sprintf to string, and only at last line of cycle call printf following by fflush. And even in this case if your buffer will be larger than a stdio buffer, you won't get an atomic operation.

Comment: Sorry. I've read code badly. Maybe you'll try to define in `private` only z and in other cycles write `(for int y = …`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define OMP_NUM_THREADS 4
#define X 50
#define Y 50
#define Z 50

double dtime(){
 double t;
 struct timeval tv;
 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
 t = tv.tv_sec + ((double)tv.tv_usec)/1e6;
 return t;
}

int main(int argv, char **argc){
 double V[X][Y][Z];
 double Vnew[X][Y][Z];
 int z;

 for (int z=0;z<Z;z++)
  for (int y=0;y<Y;y++)
   for (int x=0;x<X;x++)
    V[x][y][z] = 3.*x+2.*y+z;

double t0 = dtime();
#pragma omp parallel for shared(V, Vnew)
 for(z=1;z<Z;z++)
  for(int y=1;y<Y;y++)
   for(int x=1;x<X;x++)
     Vnew[x][y][z] = sin(V[x][y][z])*cos(V[x][y][z])+log(V[x][y][z]);
 printf("time: %g\n", dtime() - t0);
 FILE *userfile=fopen("out" ,"w");
 fprintf(userfile,"vtk header\n");
 for (z=0;z<Z;z++)
  for (int y=0;y<Y;y++)
   for (int x=0;x<X;x++)
    fprintf(userfile,"%g ",Vnew[x][y][z]);
}
```

Compiling:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -lm 1.c
```

After running on my machine (4-core) it give:

```
time: 0.0224061
```

When I comment `#pragma omp`, I get:

```
time: 0.059217
```

Comment: Im sorry if im being a total noob. but does that mean there is anything inherantly wrong with my parralised loops? 

and the first loop is the most critical and MYO is a large function to call.

Comment: Take this `dtime` function and compare time with and without openmp. Sometimes too many parameters only slow down execution.

Answer (score 0):

We have made progress in getting the parralleising to work in openmp but only for small files (will run for arrays 20x20x20, 50x50x50 but not for 100...) with 20x20x20 being slower and 50x50x50 being significantly faster. but we need it to work with much larger arrars in the longrun

for the larger files it writes the first outfile for the first time loop and fails to write the rest (observed with the smaller array sizes) because it works with the smaller array sizes we were wondering if this could be a memory issue?